# PHP MongoDB extension/class issues only with CLI

Tags: php, mongodb, command-line-interface

- cd /etc/php5
- `apache2/php.ini` and `cli/php.ini` are identical
- `apache2/conf.d/mongo.ini` and `cli/conf.d/mongo.ini` are identical

The mongo extension doesn't get loaded when I try to execute the script via command line (I get a class not found error).
Works perfectly through apache.

Any ideas? (I wrote this tiny script to check):

```
<?php
    echo class_exists('Mongo') ? "Mongo class found" : "Mongo class not found" . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

When this file is hit through apache, it echoes affirmative, negative via CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely using the wrong php file then. Use `php --ini` to see which ones it loads. You can also set the `php.ini` settings `display_errors=1` and `display_startup_errors=1` to  see what a reason for it not being loaded could be.

Comment: You are right! php --ini showed that cli loaded a different php.ini Adding extension=mongo.so to that php.ini will make mongo work under cli. Thanks!